# What was the (unsolved) clue that would have revealed the location of Redbeard?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In "The Final Problem," we learn of the unsolved disappearance of Redbeard,

> initially presented as Sherlock's dog but later revealed to have been a friend of his.

We are told that the young Eurus had both arranged the disappearance and presented her family with a clue that would have revealed his location, and that when they could not solve the clue, she allowed him to die.

She gives the same (?) clue to Sherlock years later,

> when she has hidden Dr. Watson in the same location.

This time he succeeds, finding the answer

> "in my (Eurus's) room".

In what way could this possibly have been the correct answer at the time of Redbeard's original disappearance?

Comment: The gravestones... Right?

Comment: Playing with her, allowing her in his group, was the Eurus's key/goal . Then we can suppose that she would have told Sherlock the location, as it happened in the "present".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In what way could this possibly have been the correct answer at the time of Redbeard's original disappearance?

**It wasn't about finding Redbeard**...it was about getting Sherlock to love her and play with her...because they wouldn't let her play 'pirates'.

The *answer* was to get that to happen.

The original song/poem was encoded....

[image]

The decoded poem goes:

> *I am lost*
>
> *Help me brother*
>
> *Save My Life*
>
> *Before ... my ... Doom.*
>
> *I am Lost Without your love*
>
> *Save My soul*
>
> *seek my room.*

### [image]

> EURUS: You’re playing with me, Sherlock. We’re playing the game.
>
> SHERLOCK: The game, yes. I get it now. (He steps closer to her.) **The song was never a set of directions.**
>
> [snip]...
>
> SHERLOCK (softly, stroking her hair): Now, you ... you just ... you just went the wrong way last time, that’s all.